# System hangs with the message "A Script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding"

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

In a page, there are a set of combo boxes and after clicking on "add", another set of combo boxes appear to be selected.  While recording the user actions in selenium ide, am getting the following error when clicked on the second set of combo box:

> A Script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script or you can continue to see if the script will complete.
>   Script: chrome//selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/lib/sizzle.js:2

The system hangs after this.

The same user action can be done manually without any problem.

But, if the selenium ide window is open, am getting the same error when done manually also.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Are you useing the [latest 1.8.1 version](http://seleniumhq.org/download/)? If yes, you should consider [filing a bug](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/entry).

Comment: I was using the old version.  But verified again with selenium ide 1.8.1 version.  For this version, the alert message doesnt appear but the system hangs. Filed an issue for the same.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal if the page has a huge amount of data. When this occur you need to give more time to webdriver using a wait expression. A implicit wait should be solve it:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implictly_wait(5)
driver.get("yout page")
driver.find_elem...
```

I hope this may solve your problem.